# Insert 2 html table cells that cover 3 rows

Tags: html, html-table

In [this Html table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxYwm.png) , how could I insert the cells "XPath" and "XSL transformations" as each of them covers 1.5 row (the 2 cells cover equally 3 rows).
How should I use the "rowspan" attribute ?

Answer (score 2):

```
<td rowspan = "number">table content...</td>
```

**Another example**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Ajay</td>
        <!-- This cell will take up space on two rows -->
        <td rowspan="2">24</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Priya</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank your for your answer.   Yes I know how to use "rowspan" attribute, but my question is how to use it to insert 2 table cells that cover equally 3 rows?(see picture please)   Is it possible to set the value of "rowspan" to 1.5??